# Element not found for Input elements on Selenide + Appium

Tags: kotlin, appium, selenide

I'm writing Android Web automated test using Kotlin+Selenide+Appium. There's already working Desktop Web version of those tests on Kotlin+Selenide.

`Koltin 1.2.31`
`Selenide:4.11.1`
`Appium:java-client:5.0.4`
`Appium: 1.7.2`

Test starts, appium server starts, browser on my device starts, page opens, element is located but it cannot `setValue` for it. Test works well except for Input elements and manipulations on it.

In test, I clear the field at first, then I set value for it. It actually find the element, clears it and then throws the error on that step (clear the field). So it clears the field but it also cannot found it???
Errors that appear:

`Element not found {.project-scope-main-header-content-input > div > input}
Expected: exist`

`Caused by: WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'`

I tried to run the tests with and without these 2 capabilities:

`capa.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true)`

`capa.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true)`

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

EDIT: The problem is in outdated ChromeDriver which I cannot update for some reasons.

EDIT#2: 
Here's how I initialize it: 
`

```
lateinit var driver: AppiumDriver<SelenideElement>
private val appiumServer = AppiumRunAndStop()

@BeforeClass
@Parameters("platform")
fun setUp(platform : String) {
    appiumServer.restartServer()
    when (platform) {
        "Android" -> {
            val capa = DesiredCapabilities()
            capa.setCapability("automationName", "Appium")
            //capa.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 150)
            capa.setCapability("platformName", "Android")
            capa.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0")
            capa.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 6P")
            capa.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome")
            capa.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true)
            capa.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true)
            capa.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "pathh\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
            driver = AppiumDriver(URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capa)
            sleep(2000)
            WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver)

        }
        "iOS" -> {
            //TO DO
        }
        else -> println("Platform is not correct")
    }
    Configuration.baseUrl = "my_url"
}`
```

It works with this `capa.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "pathh\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")` but I want it to autoupdate the ChromeDriver automatially.

Comment: Still cannot fix this :( any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. My test uses outdated ChromeDriver (chromedriver=2.33.506120).

I don't know how to update it for this test. 
`WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version("2.37").setup()` doesn't help. 
 `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")` either doesn't help.

I also tried to do this:

```
val options = ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome")
capa.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options)`
```

EDIT: Worked with `capa.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "PATH")` but why Selenide doesn't update ChromeDriver by itself?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried using `element.sendKeys("your value")` method to enter values and `element.clear()` to clear the text from the element?

This approach works for me. Also avoid using beta version of Appium Java client and always use a stable version which is 5.0.4.

Comment: Yes, I do `element.clear()` before `element.sendKeys("val")`. I also tried to use `element.value = "val"` and without `.clear()`. 5.0.4 version didn't help either.

Comment: Can you try one more thing, tap on that element before clear and sendkeys.

Comment: weird, I'm getting an error `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8 cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.internal.HasIdentity` on `action.tap(element)`. Don't know what's happening.

Comment: Can you also try clicking on it instead of tap?

Comment: I tried. It clicks. I also verify that element is `visible` before `.clear()`. Element is cleared but then it throws the error that it doesn't exist. When I don't use `Appium Keyboard` I see standard Android Keyboard appears when field is focused. But it doesn't enter any data.

Comment: Did you try using only Appium alone instead of using it with Selenide and kotlin? Because there's no reason why it shouldn't work. I've used my own Appium wrapper framework and it worked alright.

Comment: the problem is in outdated ChromeDriver but I cannot update it somehow :/